# react js using BrowserRouter: it's blank when I deploy to an apache server

Tags: reactjs

I have react js app and it works perfectly on the local server. But when I upload it to the an apache server, everything is blank, so I have looked over google and the solutions am getting is that i use
HashRouter
instead of
BrowserRouter.
When I do that, it works but it brings another problem where when I navigate to some of the pages, there is no history and the page breaks again now with an error of undefined history state. Anybody who can help me around this, please guide me along. It's a big headache to me.

Comment: Do you use Cache for server pages ? Sometimes, with Symfony, it break the cache, so I have to reset it, sometimes apache too, to make it work.

Comment: no i dont use cache

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `.htaccess` file or create virtual host so that all traffics are send in index.html file e.g you can see in this [node server](https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/expensify/blob/master/server/server.js#L9-L11) I always send all my traffic to my `index.html` file. You can search in Google for this & find one. I found one https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042 but as I didn't test so I don't guarantee but I hope you got the idea ️

Comment: Good idea ! Now, you can use FallbackResource too without mod_rewrie.

Comment: am not using nodejs, am just using apache, is that where am going wrong or what?